# Sorting List according to split

Tags: java, android, string, sorting, split

I have a `List` of quite long `Strings`:

```
test:test:test:test:test:test:test:ABC:test:test:test:test:test:test:  
test:test:test:test:test:test:test:DEF:test:test:test:test:test:test:  
test:test:test:test:test:test:test:GHI:test:test:test:test:test:test:  
test:test:test:test:test:test:test:JKL:test:test:test:test:test:test:  
test:test:test:test:test:test:test:MNO:test:test:test:test:test:test:
```

Assume all tests as different from each other. I would like to sort these Strings based on that particular location where capital letters are held.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < aList.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(list.get(i).toString().split(":")[7]);
    }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`Collections.sort()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator)) and provide a custom [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) to impose your desired ordering criteria.

Here's an example (check for nulls and unexpected formats ommited):

```
List<String> myList;
Collections.sort(myList, new Comparator<String>(){
    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        String text1 = o1.split(":")[7];
        String text2 = o2.split(":")[7];
        return text1.compareTo(text2);
    }
});
```